# Center a Tooltip Dynamically

Tags: html, css, styling

I'm trying to center a tooltip but I want that when it overflows it moves to the right or left depending on where is located.

Here is the example. I want that the tooltip in this case moves to the right, but if the bell is in a location where there can't be a overflow, the tooltip have to be centered.

```css
:root {
    --blue: hsl(190, 10%, 60%);
    --dark: hsl(0, 0%, 10%);
    --dark-light: hsl(0, 0%, 50%);
    --light: hsl(0, 0%, 100%);
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    height: 100vh;
    display: grid;
}

.main {
    max-height: 100%;
    margin: 10px;
    display: flex;
    border: 1px solid var(--dark-light);
}

.notifications {
  margin:10px;
}

.notifications::before{
  content: 'hover over bell';
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.notifications-content {
    height: 25px;
    width: 25px;
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

.notifications-content svg {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.notifications-content::after {
    content: attr(notifications-tooltip);
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    background-color: var(--dark);
    color: white;
    overflow: auto;
    padding: 5px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 110%;
    transition: opacity 0.5s;
}

.notifications-content:hover::after {
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Mastering Front End</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class='main'>
        <div class="notifications">
            <div class='notifications-content' notifications-tooltip='Here are your notifications'>
               <svg id="Layer_4" enable-background="new 0 0 24 24" height="512" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="512" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><g><path d="m21.379 16.913c-1.512-1.278-2.379-3.146-2.379-5.125v-2.788c0-3.519-2.614-6.432-6-6.92v-1.08c0-.553-.448-1-1-1s-1 .447-1 1v1.08c-3.387.488-6 3.401-6 6.92v2.788c0 1.979-.867 3.847-2.388 5.133-.389.333-.612.817-.612 1.329 0 .965.785 1.75 1.75 1.75h16.5c.965 0 1.75-.785 1.75-1.75 0-.512-.223-.996-.621-1.337z"/><path d="m12 24c1.811 0 3.326-1.291 3.674-3h-7.348c.348 1.709 1.863 3 3.674 3z"/></g></svg>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You may have to use javascript to check the position x axis relative to the window of the parent. Since we work left to right in English, which I assume is the language you will be using, you can check the position of the parent element relative to the windows right edge. If it is less than the width of the tooltip then position the tooltip to the right of the parent element.

Comment: You can't manipulate :after, because it's not technically part of the DOM and therefore is inaccessible by any JavaScript. But you can add a new class with a new :after specified.

Comment: oh ok, I thought there was a way to make it purely with CSS, thanks you all

Comment: You can manipulate pseudo elements using root variables with javascript. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Using Java Script, you can use ***root*** variables to set your ***units*** that are being used in your ***pseudo elements***. Using javascript you can get the position of elements in the `document.documentElement` and mathematically figure out there ***positions***, then use ***conditionals*** to check the ***position*** of the element in relation to the ***windows*** edge to ***position*** the tool tip properly in the dom.

Below is a rudimentary example of how this can be done using your code. I have placed notes in the Java Script to hopefully help you further understand what is going on.

```js
// set the root to the document.documentElement HTML element
const root = document.documentElement;
// get the .main element
const main = document.querySelector('.main');
// get the .notification-content element
const ntfctnsCntnt = document.querySelectorAll('.notifications-content');

// getBoundingClientRect() and computed styles
const mainRect = main.getBoundingClientRect()
const mainRight = mainRect.x + mainRect.width
const compStyleRoot = getComputedStyle(root);
const ttContWidth = compStyleRoot.getPropertyValue('--tt-cont-width');
const rootRect = root.getBoundingClientRect();

// run each nodeList through a loop
ntfctnsCntnt.forEach(el => {
  // event listener on hover (mouseover)
  el.addEventListener('mouseover', e => {
    // set the event targets boundingClientRect
    const elRect = e.target.getBoundingClientRect()
    // e.targets width
    const elWidth = elRect.width;
    // get width of tooltip before DOM changes it using root variable
    let ttcWidth = ttContWidth;
    // if the tooltips width is greater than the windows left "0" + parent left => "main" 
    // which will be padding and/or margin, + the bell elements left then we set the 
    // tooltip to the right of the "bell" element

    // "parseInt(ttContWidth.split('px')[0]) we are removing the px portion from the string
    // and parsing this string as an integer so it can be compared with another number
    if (parseInt(ttContWidth.split('px')[0]) > rootRect.left + mainRect.left + elRect.left) {
      // set the varibale for --ttp-left-pos (left: ) to window.left + main.left + e.target.left
      // which will be right of the element
      root.style.setProperty(`--ttp-left-pos`, rootRect.left + mainRect.left + elRect.left + 'px')
    } else {
    // else we set the tooltip to the left of the "bell" element
      root.style.setProperty(`--ttp-left-pos`, `-${parseInt(ttContWidth.split('px')[0]) + elWidth}px` )
    }
  })
})
```

```css
:root {
  --blue: hsl(190, 10%, 60%);
  --dark: hsl(0, 0%, 10%, 0.8);
  --dark-light: hsl(0, 0%, 50%);
  --light: hsl(0, 0%, 100%);
  --ttp-left-pos:0;
  --ttp-top-pos:100%;
  --tt-cont-width:100px;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  display: grid;
}

.main {
  max-height: 100%;
  margin: 10px;
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid var(--dark-light);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.notifications:nth-of-type(1) {
  margin: 10px;
}

.notifications::before {
  content: 'hover over bell';
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.notifications-content {
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  position: relative;
}

.notifications:nth-of-type(2) {
  margin-top: 10px; 
}


.notifications-content svg {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.notifications-content::after {
  content: attr(notifications-tooltip);
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  background-color: var(--dark);
  color: white;
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  top: var(--ttp-top-pos);
  left: var(--ttp-left-pos);
  transition: opacity 0.5s;
  width: var(--tt-cont-width);
}

.notifications-content:hover::after {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Mastering Front End</title>
  
</head>

<body>
  <div class='main'>
    <div class="notifications">
      <div class='notifications-content' notifications-tooltip='Here are your notifications'>
        <svg id="Layer_4" enable-background="new 0 0 24 24" height="512" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="512" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><g><path d="m21.379 16.913c-1.512-1.278-2.379-3.146-2.379-5.125v-2.788c0-3.519-2.614-6.432-6-6.92v-1.08c0-.553-.448-1-1-1s-1 .447-1 1v1.08c-3.387.488-6 3.401-6 6.92v2.788c0 1.979-.867 3.847-2.388 5.133-.389.333-.612.817-.612 1.329 0 .965.785 1.75 1.75 1.75h16.5c.965 0 1.75-.785 1.75-1.75 0-.512-.223-.996-.621-1.337z"/><path d="m12 24c1.811 0 3.326-1.291 3.674-3h-7.348c.348 1.709 1.863 3 3.674 3z"/></g></svg>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="notifications">
      <div class='notifications-content' notifications-tooltip='Here are your notifications'>
        <svg id="Layer_5" enable-background="new 0 0 24 24" height="512" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="512" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><g><path d="m21.379 16.913c-1.512-1.278-2.379-3.146-2.379-5.125v-2.788c0-3.519-2.614-6.432-6-6.92v-1.08c0-.553-.448-1-1-1s-1 .447-1 1v1.08c-3.387.488-6 3.401-6 6.92v2.788c0 1.979-.867 3.847-2.388 5.133-.389.333-.612.817-.612 1.329 0 .965.785 1.75 1.75 1.75h16.5c.965 0 1.75-.785 1.75-1.75 0-.512-.223-.996-.621-1.337z"/><path d="m12 24c1.811 0 3.326-1.291 3.674-3h-7.348c.348 1.709 1.863 3 3.674 3z"/></g></svg>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```